# Rewrite url page not found .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite my url with .htaccess to beautify my urls but I'm getting page error. What surprises me is that it's working on my friend's machine using xampp and I'm using apache on my linux machine.

```
# Turn Rewrite Engine On
RewriteEngine On

 # Rewrite for info.php?id=xx
 RewriteRule ^photos/([0-9]+) info.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

 # Rewrite for profile.php?user=xx
 RewriteRule ^user/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) profile.php?user=$1 [NC,L]

 # Rewrite for logout.php?redirec=xx
 RewriteRule ^logout/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) logout.php?redirect=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Did you check your `RewriteBase`?

Comment: Should I include a `RewriteBase` in my `.htaccess`?

Comment: I always set mine to `/`, just in case. It all depends on if you have access to your true Apache conf file. (If you didn't know, the `^` sign represents the rewrite base)

Comment: I have added it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The most probable cause of error appears to be that `mod_rewrite` is not loaded. Check apache's `httpd.conf` file, and search for the line:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

If there is a `#` before it, remove that and restart the server.